# Попытка использовать make search во FreeBSD приводит к ошибке

Tags: freebsd

Пишу команду:

```
make search key="Python packages"
```

Ответ:

> make: don't know how to make search. Stop
>   make: stopped in /root

Что делать?

Comment: Перейти сначала в /usr/ports ?

Comment: нету!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: http://www.ru.freebsd.org/doc/ru/books/handbook/ports-using.html почитайте

Comment: Лучше начать отсюда http://www.ru.freebsd.org/doc/ru/books/handbook/ports.html

Comment: @cronfy Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @Sergey Спешу попросить вас также публиковать развернутые ответы, содержащие минимальный пример решения.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Если уж руководство по freebsd не достаточно полное, то куда уж мне.

Comment: @Sergey Уверен, оно полное. На Stack Overflow принято публиковать минимальное решение прямо в ответе, дополняя его ссылкой на источник. Если ссылка в документации изменится, то вопрос потеряет всякую ценность для сообщества. Более того, вопрос, где ответ находится по ссылке намного сложнее понять. Было бы крайне здорово увидеть минимальный пример реализации с вашими рекомендациями.

Comment: Вам нужно сначала скачать и распаковать порты `portsnap fetch; portsnap extract` , подробнее по моей ссылке выше. Потом перейти в /usr/ports, и там уже `make search`

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky написал, но ваши ремарки применимы для ответов, а здесь комментарии. На мои вопросы я также получал ответ в комментарии в виде ссылки, был этим удовлетворен и не вижу никакой проблемы. В комментариях можно быстро помочь автору, если вопрос тривиальный - ссылки здесь достаточно.

Comment: @cronfy Вопросы задаются и отвечаются по большей мере не для авторов, а для сотен и тысяч их коллег, которые попадут на вопрос из поиска. Ответ–ссылка, как и комментарий, губительны для системы. Ссылку может предоставить и поисковик, но ваш личный опыт – никто, кроме вас!

Answer (score 3):

Команда `make search` не ищет по какой-то абстрактной базе данных - это обёртка для работы с деревом портов, которое локально должно быть развёрнуто на том хосте, где она выполняется. Причём искать она будет именно по локальной версии дерева, а не по "последним официально зарелизившимся портам" - если у Вас дерево портов не обновлялось полгода, то ничего "нового" поиск не покажет.

Чтобы `make search` работал так, как Вы хотите, необходимо перед выполнением этой команды перейти в каталог `/usr/ports`. Если такого каталога у Вас нет (или он пуст) - нужно сначала развернуть дерево портов. Вкратце - делается это командой `portsnap fetch extract` (первый раз, чтобы скачать и развернуть дерево портов) и `portsnap fetch update` (каждый раз, когда есть необходимость актуализировать дерево), обе команды выполнять нужно от рута. Подробнее можно прочитать в [документации](http://www.ru.freebsd.org/doc/ru/books/handbook/ports-using.html), как Вам уже указал коллега в комментариях к вопросу.

В Интернете Вы также можете встретить инструкции по работе с деревом портов с помощью `cvsup` - их игнорируйте, это наследие далёкого прошлого и делать так сегодня стало моветоном.